# How do I turn an RDD into a dictionary in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, key-value

So I have an RDD that I need to turn into a dictionary. However, I'm getting a few errors and I'm stuck.

First thing I do is pull in my csv file:

```
dataset = spark.read.csv('/user/myuser/testing_directory/output_csv', inferSchema = True, header = True)
```

Then I collect the data into an RDD:

```
pre_experian_rdd = dataset.collect()
```

So my data looks like so:

```
Row(name='BETTING Golf Course', address='1234 main st', city_name='GARDEN HOUSE', state='OH', zipcode=45209)
```

I need to keep the same structure with the key:value for the entire row because I need to make a api call. So it would need to be: `{name:value, address:value, city_name:value, state:value, zipcode:value}

But when I do collectAsMap() I get the following error:

```
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required
```

I need the headers in there to represent the key:value

### Can someone provide some insight in what I'm doing wrong, please?

Here is a snippit of my code:

dataset = spark.sparkContext.textFile('/user/myuser/testing_directory/output_csv')

pre_experian_rdd = dataset.collectAsMap()
Error message:

```
An error was encountered:
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 36; 2 is required
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1587, in collectAsMap
    return dict(self.collect())
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 36; 2 is required
```

When I load it as a CSV, I have a do a few transformations:

dataset = spark.read.csv('/user/myuser/testing_directory/output_csv', inferSchema = True, header = True)

```
ex_rdd = dataset.collect()
```

So my rdd looks something like this:

```
[Row(name='BEAR LAKE GOLF COURSE & RESORT', address='PO BOX 331', city_name='GARDEN CITY', state='UT', zipcode=84028), Row(name='CHRISTENSEN & PETERSON, INC.', address='39 N MAIN ST', city_name='RICHFIELD', state='UT', zipcode=84701), Row(name='ALEXANDERS PRECISION MACHINING', address='15731 CHEMICAL LANE', city_name='HUNTINGTON BEACH', state='CA', zipcode=92649), Row(name='JOSEPH & JANET COLOMBO', address='1003 W COLLEGE', city_name='BOZEMAN', state='MT', zipcode=59715)
```

If I do `ex_rdd.collectAsMap()` I get the following errorL

```
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required
```

To get around this I have to do the following:

```
df_dict = [row.asDict() for row in dataset.collect()]
[{'name': 'BEAR  RESORT', 'address': 'POP 331', 'city_name': 'GARDEN LAKE', 'state': 'UT', 'zipcode': 12345}, {'name': 'CHRISTENSEN INC.', 'address': '12345 MAIN AVE', 'city_name': 'FAIRFIELD', 'state': 'UT', 'zipcode': 12345}, {'name': 'PRECISE MARCHING', 'address': '1234 TESTING LANE', 'city_name': 'HUNTINGTON BEACH', 'state': 'CA', 'zipcode': 92649}]
```

The issue with this is that it's still a list and I need a dictionary.

Comment: When you do a collect, you will get a list of row objects, not an rdd. you can try dataset.rdd.collectAsMap() for your scenario

Comment: @HArdRese7 when I do collectAsMap() that's when "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required"

Comment: Provide your code so that we can see collectAsMap method statement you are using. look at flatMap and foldBykey rdd methods and see if it works. Please provide sample data and code so that the error can be reproduced for finding solution.

Comment: @HArdRese7 I updated the issue with some of my code. I hope that makes the issue a but clearer.